# libgit2sharp only commit changes for a specific file

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Is there a way to only commit the changes for a specific file using libgit2sharp? i'm looking for the equivlanent of something like, git commit -m'single file' test.txt

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can stage the file or files you want to commit.

```
Commands.Stage(repo, files);
repo.Commit(message, author, committer);
```

Garrick